# AWS cross region lambda database access

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

Recently [some service in us-west-1 seems not working](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=754988), so I'm trying to create a lambda that can access cross-region RDS (from `us-east-1` to `us-west-1`), but I cannot find any solution or sample with these keywords. Does that means cross-region database is unavailable?

As I know, use lambda reach to database in VPC may cause out of IP issues, so is there any best practice for this?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Lambda functions run outside the VPC by default. In the setup of the Lambda you can opt to give them access to a VPC which creates a network endpoint inside your VPC. Lambda uses that network endpoint to access the VPC.

The challenge you face is that your us-west-1 VPC is not visible in us-east-1. 
Suggestion: Setup VPC peering between the two VPCs and run the lambda in the us-east-1 VPC.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @user7345055, OK I'll try this, but how to solve the out of IP issue for VPC issue?

Comment: I found that "You cannot create a VPC peering connection between VPCs in different regions." in AWS document: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/PeeringGuide/vpc-peering-overview.html, so how can I build cross region VPC peering? any unofficial guideline?

Comment: cross region VPC seems not developed yet (https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=747693)

Comment: For those who find this from Google, limited cross-region VPC was announced in November 2017: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/11/announcing-support-for-inter-region-vpc-peering/  And there's a guide for cross-region connectivity available here: https://aws.amazon.com/answers/networking/aws-multiple-region-multi-vpc-connectivity/